# What do I need to do to correct this SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

1. `products` - contains products in inventory.
2. `suppliers` - contains supplier details.
3. `product_category` - contains the names of product categories.
4. `product_suppliers` - contains relationships between products and suppliers.

The important one here is probably, `product_suppliers`, so here are the columns:

```
id //(auto-increment)  
prod_id //(id of product)  
sup_id //(id of supplier)  
preferred //(1 if it's the preferred supplier for that product - 0 if not)  
cost_per_outer //(this suppliers price for this item)  
qty_in_outer //(the number in a box)
```

The `product` table, among storing the product details, also has a field for `stock_level` and `reorder_level`. When the former is less than the latter, the product should be included in the list for re-ordering.

I'm trying to build the query for the list, which is not working quite right.

I have 4 items qualified for re-ordering affecting two suppliers. There should be two items for each supplier, but currently it is only retrieving the results for the first supplier.

I'm using MySQL and PHP.

I've run the following query to give us some insight to the actual data in the database:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->         p.prod_id,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.alt_id, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                         AS sku,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_name, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                      AS prod_name,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_type, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                    AS prod_type,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.stock_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                    AS stock_level,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.reorder_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')            AS reorder_level,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(c.category_name, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')            AS category_name,
    ->         ps.sup_id,
    ->         ps.preferred
    -> FROM
    ->         products p
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->         product_category c
    ->   ON
    ->         p.category_id = c.category_id
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->         product_supplier ps
    ->   ON
    ->         p.prod_id = ps.prod_id
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->         suppliers s
    ->   ON
    ->         ps.sup_id = s.supplier_id
    -> ORDER BY
    ->         ps.sup_id;
+---------+------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| prod_id | sku  | prod_name       | prod_type | stock_level | reorder_level | category_name | sup_id | preferred |
+---------+------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
|       7 | 7    | Term Block      | 1         | 3           | 5             | Electrical    |      2 |         1 |
|       5 | 5    | Electrical Tape | 1         | 12          | 20            | Electrical    |      2 |         1 |
|       6 | 6    | BlowGas         | 1         | 6           | 15            | Plumbing      |     12 |         1 |
|       1 | 1    | PTFE Tape       | 1         | 9           | 10            | Plumbing      |     12 |         1 |
+---------+------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

Here is the query for the list with result showing only two of the four items I was expecting:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->         p.prod_id,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.alt_id, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                         AS sku,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_name, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                AS prod_name,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_desc, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                 AS prod_desc,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.stock_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')                AS stock_level,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.reorder_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')             AS reorder_level,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.reorder_qty, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')               AS reorder_qty,
    ->         p.vat_exempt,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.lastorderdate, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')            AS lastorderdate,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.lastorderqty, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')               AS lastorderqty,
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(c.category_name, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')          AS category_name,
    ->         ps.sup_id
    -> FROM
    ->         products p
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->         product_category c
    ->   ON
    ->         p.category_id = c.category_id
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->         product_supplier ps
    ->   ON
    ->         p.prod_id = ps.prod_id
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->         suppliers s
    ->   ON
    ->         ps.sup_id = s.supplier_id
    -> WHERE
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_type, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht') = 1
    ->   AND
    ->           AES_DECRYPT(p.stock_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht') <= AES_DECRYPT(p.reorder_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht')
    ->   AND
    ->           ps.preferred = 1
    -> ORDER BY
    ->         ps.sup_id;
+---------+------+-----------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
| prod_id | sku  | prod_name       | prod_desc              | stock_level | reorder_level | reorder_qty | vat_exempt | lastorderdate | lastorderqty | category_name | sup_id |
+---------+------+-----------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
|       7 | 7    | Term Block      | Nylon connector block. | 3           | 5             | 20          |          0 | NULL          | NULL         | Electrical    |      2 |
|       5 | 5    | Electrical Tape | Black                  | 12          | 20            | 100         |          0 | NULL          | NULL         | Electrical    |      2 |
+---------+------+-----------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: Why do you use `AES_DECRYPT()` for every column? If everything is encrypted, indexes are not going to work very well (if at all)

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/encryption-and-compression-functions/aes_decrypt().php : MySQL AES_DECRYPT() function decrypts an encrypted **string**...

Comment: Because this is part of an accounting system where most fields need to be encrypted. Would love to hear of a better solution if you have one though?

Comment: All field containing personnal data can be crypted, but generally, id do not need to be encrypted. So, you should remove your `AES_DECRYPT` for all column that are not VARCHAR (especially for primary key, foreign key - which should be both indexed)

Comment: Your query is looking correct, can you post sample data for the 2 products which are eligible for reordering, also check the 2nd product not appearing in the result is of `prod_type = 1` and there is a `preferred supplier` for that product.

Comment: I do believe that my id columns are not encrypted (alt_id is encrypted though but it's actually mislabelled as it contains the product sku, which is freeform vanity text field.

Comment: at this stage check the ps.preferred = 1 set all to 1. also how about level equal re-order level you still need to re-order right?

Comment: Good point Tony, amended my code.

Comment: @Meherzad I've amended my question to incorporate the diagnostic data you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your result is coming from AES_DECRYPT() is coming of `string` type and that is why comparing for stock_level and reorder level values of `3 - 5` and `12 - 20` it is showing while for `6 -15` and `9 - 20` it is not showing because if you comapre 6 and 15 as string 6 will be more than 15 same is the case for 9 and 20.

Hope you got your problem...

Convert the result of AES_DECRYPT() to numeric before comparison..

Change your where clause to this

```
WHERE
     (AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_type, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht') + 0) = 1 AND
     (AES_DECRYPT(p.stock_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht') + 0) <= (AES_DECRYPT(p.reorder_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht') + 0)
```

adding `+0` will cast the result to numeric

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_type, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht',varchar) = 1
    ->   AND
    ->           AES_DECRYPT(p.stock_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht',varchar) <= AES_DECRYPT(p.reorder_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht',varchar)
```

or :

```
WHERE
    ->         AES_DECRYPT(p.prod_type, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht',int) = 1
    ->   AND
    ->           AES_DECRYPT(p.stock_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht',varchar) <= AES_DECRYPT(p.reorder_level, 'MW4KQLg1Irfo3Xz7Nxht',varchar)
```

from : http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01015.1510/html/iqsecure/Functions_s_4132405.htm

> If you do not use a CAST statement while inserting data using the
>   AES_ENCRYPT function, you can view the same data using the AES_DECRYPT
>   function by passing VARCHAR as the data-type. If you do not pass
>   data-type to AES_DECRYPT, VARBINARY data type is returned.

Comment: Thanks for trying but I tried this but got the following error. Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) = 1.